# Issue while installing airflow in conda virtual environment

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I have followed a number of steps but could not get airflow up and running in my conda virtual environment.

below are the steps I have followed.

Issue below command in my conda environment.

pip install apache-airflow==1.10.10 --constraint https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/1.10.10/requirements/requirements-python3.7.txt.

There were issues regarding VC++ not present.This issue has been resolved post installation of VC++ and added it in my environment variable. I have even added AIRFLOW_HOME in my environment variable.

Unfortunately below command is not working.

airflow initdb
I have not been able to start the webserver as well.

airflow webserver -p 8080
my system is not aware of airflow.When I am issuing 'airflow initdb' commmand,I am getting below error.

(biometric) C:\Users\royan\Anaconda3\envs\biometric\lib\site-packages\airflow\bin>airflow initdb
'airflow' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Please suggest the steps I need to perform to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way to install Airflow in an Anaconda environment is to use the [conda-forge](https://conda-forge.org/) repository:

```
conda create -n airflow
conda activate airflow
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge 
conda config --env --set channel_priority strict 
conda install airflow
```

Comment: Do I need to create a different virtual environment only for airflow?Here you have created airflow virtual env to install airflow.

Comment: @AnandaRoy No, you don't have to create a separate environment, but to avoid possible conflicts (i.e. because of the broken Airflow installation in your biometric environment and probably other pip installed packages) I would start by installing Airflow in a fresh environment first. In general, try to avoid using pip. Use conda install instead and the diverse conda channels.

Comment: Thanks for your response Sergiy.I have followed the steps you mentioned but got below errors. (airflow) C:\Ananda\Workspace\notebooks>conda install apache-airflow
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - apache-airflow

Comment: @AnandaRoy I've updated the last command, please try again.

Comment: Thanks Sergiy for your response.However,I got below error this time.(airflow) C:\Ananda\Workspace\notebooks>conda install airflow
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - airflow

Comment: It seems that conda does not have airflow package.I have used pip for this reason.But encountered in a different issue.